# function and dictionary format understanding

Tags: python, function, dictionary

Hi I need to understand this line

```
freq[x] = freq.get(x,0) + 1
```

in below code and how it is working. I know function is returning dictionary but I need to know how this line exactly works.

```
def get_frequency_dict(sequence):
    """
    Returns a dictionary where the keys are elements of the sequence
    and the values are integer counts, for the number of times that
    an element is repeated in the sequence.

    sequence: string or list
    return: dictionary
    """
    # freqs: dictionary (element_type -> int)
    freq = {}
    for x in sequence:
        freq[x] = freq.get(x,0) + 1    
    return freq
```

Comment: If you know it is a dictionary, did you find the [appropriate documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) yet?

Comment: yes I tried ,this function is in one of the helping notes. My confusion is actually the logic why 1 is being added . I mean when 'get' will already give 1 if letter is present in sequence then +1 should make it 2.

Comment: Yes, so if you already counted the letter before, and you found a second such letter, why should it *not* store 2 then?

Comment: What would happen if you gave it the string `'aa'`? What would the expected return value of the function be, and what would happen each iteration through the loop?

Comment: If some letter comes 2 times then I understand. My confusion is if some letter suppose 'a' is coming once in the sequence,then **freq.get(x,0)** will give 1 and then +1 , so why value is not becoming 2 in my that case.

Comment: It *is* becoming 2 in that case. Why do you think it is not?

Comment: Take a look at [this visualisation of the code](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def+get_frequency_dict%28sequence%29%3A%0A++++freq+%3D+%7B%7D%0A++++for+x+in+sequence%3A%0A++++++++freq%5Bx%5D+%3D+freq.get%28x,0%29+%2B+1++++%0A++++return+freq%0A%0Aprint%28get_frequency_dict%28'aa'%29%29&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=true&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=0).

Comment: because if i test it with 'a', then i get **{'a': 1}**. If its becoming 2 then it should be**a:2**. where (2= 1 from get and 1 from +1). sorry am taking so much time on this but am beginner and i want to understand the concept

Comment: oh thanks alot ,now i get it

Comment: You tested with **one character**. `a` is only there once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line uses the [`dict.get()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), which returns either the value for the given key, or a default value.

So the line

```
freq[x] = freq.get(x,0) + 1
```

stores either `1` if `x` was not found in the dictionary (so `freq.get(x, 0)` returned 0) or it increments an already existing value. In effect, this counts all the values in `sequence`, only creating keys for any value when it first encounters that value. This saves you having to pre-set all possible values as keys with the value `0`.

The whole function could be trivially replaced by a [`collections.Counter()` instance](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

def get_frequency_dict(sequence):
    """
    Returns a dictionary where the keys are elements of the sequence
    and the values are integer counts, for the number of times that
    an element is repeated in the sequence.

    sequence: string or list
    return: dictionary
    """
    return Counter(sequence)
```

Since `Counter` is a subclass of `dict`, the invariants stated in the documentation would still be satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

As refered in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), the method `get` of dictionnaries returns the value associated to a `key` (first parameter) if `key` is defined in the dict. Else, it returns the `default` value (second parameter).

```
get(dict, key, default=None):
    if key in dict:
        return dict[key]
    return default
```

In your case, the function counts the number of occurences of each element in the sequence.